# How to get the owner of an FA2 token on chain

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, ligo, fa2, nft

For an FA2 nft contract, how can I get the address of the owner of token_id 0 from inside another contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification does not enforce an implementation for this. You can only verify if a given address owns the token by calling [balance_of](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-12/tzip-12.md#balance_of) callback view. In the case of an NFT, balance `1` would mean that a given address owns that token and a balance of `0` that the address does not own it.

Check this [thread](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4334/calling-balance-of-via-smart-contract-gives-error-a-failwith-instruction-was-rea) for an example on how to do that.